# Alternative to mix-blend-mode: multiply in Internet Explorer

Tags: image, css

On my site I have several hundred images in jpg format, with a white background area (in the image itself). This has worked fine as the html/body background was also white. Images appeared to be transparent that way.

Now, I am about to change the site theme and these same images will now have a light grey html/body background color. I have tried to use the css rule `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` to make the white areas in the images transparent. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer (11).

Any suggestions on how to work around this? Just to be clear, it's not the image overall opacity I want to fix, it's only the white area in the jpg images that I want to make transparent.

If no solution is possible I will have to change the format to **png** or **gif** with transparency. That would take days to accomplish...

Comment: There's a javascript polyfill for background-blend-mode on IE. Maybe you can adapt it to work with mix-blend-mode https://codepen.io/brav0/pen/bJDxt

Comment: Thanks Facundo Corradini. I will look into that one and if it's possible to adapt.

Comment: @TBJ, have you found the way to polyfill it for mix-blend-mode?

Comment: Valera Tumash; No sorry, I did not get it to work. Images have to be edited and saved in PNG or GIF.